# PIC24/PIC16 power consumption during reset

Tags: pic, power-consumption

I am working on low power application that has long Vdd rise time. I have external power supervisor that control PIC24/PIC16 MCU reset pin. It holds MCLR pin low during Vdd stabilization period and pull it up once it's stable. The problem I am seeing is that MCU consume ~1 mA power while pulled low. This is quite high number for my application given that MCU consume only 30uA while operating normally. I checked both PIC16F527 and PIC24F08 and they consume 1mA while MCLR pulled low. Anyone has any idea where this power goes to and how to reduce that?

Comment: Do you have a 5K pullup on /MCLR?

Comment: Yes. I have 10k pullup.

Comment: Well, there's some of it.

Comment: Thank you. I am running from 5V so pullup consumes 500uA. MCU still eating 500uA.

Answer (score 1):

You can program the micro to run at 32 kHz from LPRC. When it's time to execute instructions, execute one that switches the clock to the frequency that is sufficient for the application.

Comment: I am running MCU from 32kHz internal LPRC. The problem is that when you pull MCLR low it consumes 1 mA.

Comment: have you tried internal power monitor instead of keeping a micro in reset? I was successfully starting PIC micros from PV (in the morning, the Vdd rise of those is in the order of minutes) with little difficulty. Add caps to power rail prior to attempting.